# groups.getByName(groupname) is undefined

Tags: development, javascript, client-object-model

I have copied some snippets of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122139/check-if-current-users-belongs-to-sp-group-using-javascript-client-side-object-m)

to test if a user belongs to a certain group, I am using Sharepoint 2010, however I am getting an method is undefined error.

I am making sure that sp.js is loaded with :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(removeLink, "sp.js");
});
```

then when this is loaded I check if the user is a current member:

```
    function removeLink(){
        IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Approvers", function (isCurrentUserInGroup){
        if(isCurrentUserInGroup)
   {
    alert(isCurrentUserInGroup);
   }
   else
   {
       alert(isCurrentUserInGroup + "- no");
   }
        });

    }
```

The isCurrentUserMemberOfgroup method looks like this:

```
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {

var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

        var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        currentContext.load(currentUser);

        var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
        currentContext.load(allGroups);

        var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);   //ERROR HERE
        currentContext.load(group);

        var groupUsers = group.get_users();
        currentContext.load(groupUsers);

        currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

        function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
            var userInGroup = false;
            var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
            while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
                if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                    userInGroup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }  
            OnComplete(userInGroup);
        }

        function OnFailure(sender, args) {
            OnComplete(false);
        }    
}
```

However this line causes an error:

```
        var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);   //ERROR HERE
```

allGroups is defined, however it contains no method getByName()

Comment: I'm still not sure why it is not defined, but I believe group is a pre-defined word in Sharepoint API, is it not?  Might want to rename your group variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what version of sharepoint you using ?

```
.getByName()
```

This is not in 2010 and was introduced in 2013.

The only thing i know of in 2010 that uses getbyname is getting the web role definition.

```
get_web().get_roleDefinitions().getByName("Read Only Access");
```

im sure there are other things that use it but what your looking for is only applicable in 2013 the getting of groups by name `.getByName()`.

**get groups by name in 2010:**

```
public static void GetSiteGroup()
{
      ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://basesmc2008");
      Web web = clientContext.Web;
      GroupCollection groups = web.SiteGroups;


      clientContext.Load(groups, groupitems => groupitems.Include(groupitem => groupitem.Title,
        groupitem => groupitem.Description).Where(groupitem=> groupitem.Title == "Home Owners"));

      clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/39f1a792-f881-464f-91ea-5e1d4aaef764/client-object-model-get-sitegroups-by-name

in 2013 your solution is valid!

if you are using 2010 than this is the solution:

```
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {

var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

        var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        currentContext.load(currentUser);

        var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
        currentContext.load(allGroups);


        var group = GetSiteGroup(groupName, currentContext, currentWeb);   
        currentContext.load(group);

        var groupUsers = group.get_users();
        currentContext.load(groupUsers);

        currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

        function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
            var userInGroup = false;
            var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
            while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
                if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                    userInGroup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }  
            OnComplete(userInGroup);
        }

        function OnFailure(sender, args) {
            OnComplete(false);
        }    
}

    public static void GetSiteGroup(var groupName, var clientContext, var web)
    {
          GroupCollection groups = web.SiteGroups;


          clientContext.Load(groups, groupitems => groupitems.Include(groupitem => groupitem.Title,
            groupitem => groupitem.Description).Where(groupitem=> groupitem.Title == groupName));

    }
```

done the above. but havent tested it but it should look similart to the above!

Hi All. In SP2010 I found I had to enumerate through the groups and users using javascript. Please find my code below. Hope this helps someone.

```
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {

var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

        var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        currentContext.load(currentUser);

        var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
        currentContext.load(allGroups);
        currentContext.load(allGroups, 'Include(Users)');

        currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

        function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
                 var userInGroup = false;
            var groupEnumerator = allGroups.getEnumerator();
            while (groupEnumerator.moveNext() && !userInGroup) {
                var oGroup = groupEnumerator.get_current();
                if (oGroup.get_title() == groupName) {
                    var collUser = oGroup.get_users();
                    var userEnumerator = collUser.getEnumerator();
                    while (userEnumerator.moveNext() && !userInGroup) {
                        var oUser = userEnumerator.get_current();
                        if (oUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                            userInGroup = true;
                            //break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            OnComplete(userInGroup);
        }

        function OnFailure(sender, args) {
            OnComplete(false);
        }    
}
```

Comment: no probs happy to help!

Comment: looks like its a bit of c# mixed in there ;) but I think I can work with it. thanks